# Jeb Swt dialog and table column cannot resize

Tags: java, swt

I'm coding with Jeb plugin, and using swt to show a custom dialog with table.

On OSX it works well and the column size just fit the field length, but on windows the width is too narrow to show the string. And I can't adjust it through any way.

I've tried: `table.setSize()`, `Dialog::getInitialRegion`, `shell.setSize`, `column.setWidth`. Maybe I spell some of them wrong but i've exactly tested them all. All of them just didn't work, the dialog and column kept their origin size.

Did any one met same problem before?

Comment: [git link](https://git.oschina.net/winkar/JebPlugin/blob/master/ListMethods.py/?dir=0&filepath=ListMethods.py&oid=433c4b87f50949e270850c686f69ce81bb0dcfa6&sha=c4091bc53669bed10b70edd197e64e903516d923)

Comment: Because I don't know which part of code cause the problem , I just give a link to the whole code.  All code is in this file